# Changing element's top position with animation on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to change div's top position with animation when I click on it. So I tried something like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="pink" id="pink">pink</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } 
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }
.container { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:absolute; 
    display:block; 
    top:0;  
    left:0; 
    background-color: #77c8ff; 
}
.pink {
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: #ff23f0; 
    position: absolute; 
   top:90%;
   -webkit-transition: top 1s linear ease-out;
}
```

JS (in `<HEAD>`)

```
var pink;
var topPos = 90;

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init() {
    pink = document.getElementById('pink');
    pink.onclick = function(){raiseDiv()};
}

function raiseDiv(){
    topPos -= 20;
    if (topPos <= 0) topPos = 0;
    pink.style.top = topPos+'%';
}
```

It does raise the div, but without animation. I tried to use `for` loop and with each iteration raise the div by 1 percent with setTimeout and with setInterval to create a sort of animation, but that didn't work.

So how can I make it work?

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g96mcnxj/1/) of the current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `ease` or `linear` timing function. You can't use both:

```
-webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out;
transition: top 1s ease-out;
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g96mcnxj/2/

Here is `linear` transtion [example](http://jsfiddle.net/g96mcnxj/3/).

Comment: Oh, didn't pay attention to it... Thank you! :) Have to wait a few minutes before the answer can be marked as accepted.